# Javascript removes siblings class in console, but they remain in the html

Tags: javascript, html, selectors-api

I'm working on a javascript toggle that hides all but the first elements of an article and when clicked it makes the selected article visible. I tried to make this happen by giving the first child a specific class and then selecting the siblings of the first child.

In the console, it works and the class is removed, but this doesnt happen in the html and the siblings remain invisible.

I can't use jquery for this project, I would love if I could get anwsers in plain javascript?

```js
var articleContent = document.querySelectorAll('article > *:not(:first-child');
var i;
var k;
var selector;

var h1 = document.querySelectorAll('article > *:first-child');

console.log(h1);
console.log(articleContent);

for (i = 0; i < articleContent.length; i += 1) {
  articleContent[i].classList.add('invisible');

};

for (i = 0; i < h1.length; i += 1){
  var j = i;
  h1[j].className = "click" + j;
  h1[j].onclick = function(){
    selector = document.querySelectorAll("." + h1[j].className + " ~ *");
    for (k = 0; k < selector.length; k += 1){
      var l = k;
      selector[k].classList.remove('invisible');
      console.log(selector[k]);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.invisible {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article>
    <h1>Article 1</h1>

    <section>
      <h2>Sub-title</h2>

      <p>Foo 1</p>
      <p>Foo 2</p>
    </section>

    <section>    
      <p>Foo 3</p>
    </section>

  </article>
</main>



<article>
  <h1>Article 2</h1>
  <section>
    <p>Foo 4</p>
    <p>Foo 5</p>
  </section>
</article>

<article>
  <h1>Article 3</h1>
  <section>
    <p>Foo 6</p>
    <p>Foo 7</p>
  </section>
</article>
```

Comment: Sorry, not used to best practices around here yet! Thanks for the tips. I added a simpler code and the css.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of turning the code into a Stack Snippet and differentiating the "foo"s. :-) Apologies if I messed anything up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preface: In your code, you're relying on features present only in modern browsers, so I've done the same below.

---

So the goal of the code is to hide all the articles, and then show/hide an article when the first child (the `h1`, currently) within it is clicked?

If so, I'd probably change the CSS a bit, which makes the JavaScript a lot simpler:

```js
// I always avoid creating global variables where possible
(function() {
  // A handy function for looping through QSA results
  var forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
  
  // Loop through all articles...
  forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('article'), function(article) {
    // ...collapsing them...
    article.classList.add('collapsed');
    
    // ...and adding a click handler to the first element
    // to toggle whether the article is hidden
    article.firstElementChild.addEventListener("click", function() {
      article.classList.toggle('collapsed');
    }, false);
  });
})();
```

```css
article.collapsed *:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article>
    <h1>Article 1</h1>

    <section>
      <h2>Sub-title</h2>

      <p>Foo 1</p>
      <p>Foo 2</p>
    </section>

    <section>    
      <p>Foo 3</p>
    </section>

  </article>
</main>



<article>
  <h1>Article 2</h1>
  <section>
    <p>Foo 4</p>
    <p>Foo 5</p>
  </section>
</article>

<article>
  <h1>Article 3</h1>
  <section>
    <p>Foo 6</p>
    <p>Foo 7</p>
  </section>
</article>
```

Alternately, if you want showing one article to hide all the others, that's fairly straight-forward as well:

```js
// I always avoid creating global variables where possible
(function() {
  // A handy way to loop through QSA results
  var forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
  
  // Loop through all articles...
  forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('article'), function(article) {
    // ...collapsing the article...
    article.classList.add('collapsed');
    
    // ...and adding a click handler to the first element
    // child, which:
    article.firstElementChild.addEventListener("click", function() {
      // Checks to see if this article is hidden
      if (article.classList.contains('collapsed')) {
        // Yes: Hide others, show this
        forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('article:not(.collapsed)'), function(a) {
          a.classList.add('collapsed');
        });
        article.classList.remove('collapsed');             
      } else {
        // No: Just hide this
        article.classList.add('collapsed');
      }
    }, false);
  });
})();
```

```css
article.collapsed *:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article>
    <h1>Article 1</h1>

    <section>
      <h2>Sub-title</h2>

      <p>Foo 1</p>
      <p>Foo 2</p>
    </section>

    <section>    
      <p>Foo 3</p>
    </section>

  </article>
</main>



<article>
  <h1>Article 2</h1>
  <section>
    <p>Foo 4</p>
    <p>Foo 5</p>
  </section>
</article>

<article>
  <h1>Article 3</h1>
  <section>
    <p>Foo 6</p>
    <p>Foo 7</p>
  </section>
</article>
```

Comment: @Maaike: You're welcome, I'm glad that helped. Welcome to SO!